# can't conenct to local mysql server through socket

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql, google-compute-engine, keystone

I'm working on setting up openstack's keystone service, and I'm using cloudsql to do it from compute engine. When I created the connection, I used this as my connections string:

```
sudo openstack-config --set /etc/keystone/keystone.conf \
   database connection mysql://keystone:Keystone123@173.194.242.166/keystone
```

All the proper permissions are there. And I was able to create the tables from compute engine, so I know that's good. However, when I went to start keystone, this is what I got:

```
2014-05-11 07:44:14.511 1515 CRITICAL keystone [-] OperationalError: (OperationalError) (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)") None None
```

I am not a database guru, I can do super basic sql queries. Please help. :)

Oh, and I'm connecting from a rhel instance, both are in the same zone.

Comment: Try running the following command to connec
"mysql -h173.194.242.166 -ukeystone -pKeystone123" see if you are able to connect to the server from mysql client.

Comment: Those work. I was testing it with selinux and iptables disabled as well.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the correct keystone.conf section is "sql", not "database". Try running

```
sudo openstack-config --set /etc/keystone/keystone.conf \
  sql connection mysql://keystone:Keystone123@173.194.242.166/keystone
```